# strange run-time issue: printf stops working midway

Tags: c, networking, gdb, printf

I was writing a [chat server program](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23989902/) as part of my network lab when I observed a very strange behavior:

```
        printf("Recieved login info.\n"); //works
        printf("Username: %s\n", ui->username); //works
        printf("Passward: %s\n", ui->password); //works

        //TO_AUTHENTICATE, if failure, send appropriate reply
        printf("makeitwork"); //does not work
        while(ui != NULL)
        {
                printf("here2");//does not work
                if(strcmp(ui->username, record.username) == 0 && strcmp(ui->password, record.password) == 0)
                {
                        strcpy(userRecords[sockfd].username, record.username);
                        userRecords[sockfd].status = ONLINE;

                        printf("Successfully authenticated %s.\n", userRecords[sockfd].username);

                //      sendOnlineUsers(sockfd, registeredUsers);

                        return SUCCESS;
                }
                ui = ui->next;
        }
```

In the above code segment, the first, second and third printf statements works, but from the 4th onwards, it does not work.

But if I comment out the `if` statement `printf("here2");`, everything works normally.

I used gdb to execute the program line by line:

```
(gdb) 
Recieved login info.
94      printf("Username: %s\n", ui->username);
(gdb) 
Username: user-1
95      printf("Passward: %s\n", ui->password);
(gdb) 
Passward: pass
98      printf("makeitwork");
(gdb) 
99      while(ui != NULL)
(gdb) 
101         printf("here2");
(gdb) 
102         if(strcmp(ui->username, record.username) == 0i)//&& strcmp(ui->password, record.password) == 0)
```

The printf is executing, but there is no output on the terminal.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the buffer

Add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf` where you do not have `\n` at the end

Comment: You were right. I put a `/n` and now it is working. Can you explain what is happening, and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: `Printf` puts stuff in a buffer. `\n` flushes the buffer and sends it to the terminal. Either send the new line or flush the buffer as described above